# Given the probability density of random variable $X$, what is the density of $Y=aX+b$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a random variable $X$ with probability density $f_X$ and want to determine the probability density $f_Y$ of $Y=aX+b$ with $a,b \in \Bbb R$. How do I proceed here?

Comment: We have $$\frac{dY}{dX} = a\Rightarrow dY= adX.$$
So, $$f_Y(y)dY = a f_X\left(\frac{x-b}{a}\right)dX.$$

Comment: correction, the last $a$ coefficient should be $1/a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a>0$ then: $$F_Y(x)=P(aX+b\leq x)=P\left(X\leq\frac{x-b}{a}\right)=F_X\left(\frac{x-b}{a}\right)$$

Take the derivative on both sides to find $f_Y$ expressed in $f_X$.

Have a look now at the cases $a=0$ (then no density exists) and $a<0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So checking if I get the right result: I get an additional factor $\frac{1}{a}$ from the derivation and since I'm interested in $f_Y(y)$ I simply write $y$ for $x$. So my result is $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{a} f_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)$. I'm a little unsure about the last step, though.

Comment: Your answer is correct. If $a<1$ then you come to $F_Y(x)=1-F_X(\frac{x-b}{a})$ and taking the derivative to $f_Y(x)=-\frac{1}{a}f_X(\frac{x-b}{a})$. You can switch the $x$ for $y$ if you like.

Comment: Ah, if $a<0$ then the sign in the inequality changes. Thanks again!